# Should I bind to SharedService property in WPF Prism

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, prism

I used a SharedService (Prism) to get data between two module. In the SharedService, I put a string property named AdapterName. 
Assume that in module A has ViewAViewModel and module B has ViewBViewModel

```
public class ViewAViewModel : BindableBase {
    private string _adapterNameA;
    public string AdapterNameA
    {
        get { return _adapterNameA; }
        set { SetValue (ref _adapterNameA, value); }
    }

    private ISharedService _sharedService;
    public ISharedService SharedService {
        get { return _sharedService; }
        set { SetValue (ref _sharedService, value); }
    }

    public ViewAViewModel (ISharedService sharedService) {
        _sharedService = sharedService;
    }
}

public class ViewBViewModel : BindableBase {
    private string _adapterNameB;
    public string AdapterNameB {
        get { return _adapterNameB; }
        set { SetValue (ref _adapterNameB, value); }
    }

    private ISharedService _sharedService;
    public ISharedService SharedService {
        get { return _sharedService; }
        set { SetValue (ref _sharedService, value); }
    }

    public ViewBViewModel (ISharedService sharedService) {
        _sharedService = sharedService;
    }
}

public interface ISharedService {
    string AdapterName { get; set; }
}

public class SharedService : BindableBase, ISharedService {
    private string _adapterName;
    public string AdapterName {
        get { return _adapterName; }
        set { SetValue (ref _adapterName, value); }
    }
}
```

I have a textbox both ViewA and ViewB, and I want the value in the textbox in ViewA always the same as in ViewB. So should I change SharedService.AdapterName value in AdapterNameA get, set (similar with AdapterNameB)?

```
public string AdapterNameA
{
    get { 
        _adapterNameA = SharedService.AdapterName;
        return _adapterNameA;
        }
    set { 
        SetValue (ref _adapterNameA, value); 
        SharedService.AdapterName = value;
    }
}
```

or binding directly to SharedService property

```
Text = "{Binding Path=SharedService.AdapterName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

or another way? (I am trying making WPF MVVM with Prism)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the shared service implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` event and raise change notifications you could bind to its property directly provided that you really want to expose the service through a property of the view model(s). You might not want to do this dependening on what the service does.

If you don't want to expose the service, you're left with creating wrapper properties in the view models. This provides better encapsulation at the expense of some extra lines of code for the wrapper properties (if you have several).

But there is no real right or wrong here. You will have to decide which solution that makes most sense for you in this particular scenario.

In general, a service is supposed to abstract away and take care of fetching some results from somewhere and pass these back to the view model. It doesn't typically implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` event and expose properties that the views bind directly to. It's the responsbility of the view model to define and expose this properties. The view model may still use the service to populate the properties.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your explanation has answered a few of my questions. I have one more question In case I want to get a property value from ViewA when clicking on a button in ViewB, how should I do?

Comment: Please ask a new question if you have another issue. Don't ask additional questions in the comments field.